# How can I Select where field of date type on google datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to select some data from google datastore comparing a date condition like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM entity 
WHERE field_date < 2016-02-01
```

I searched for this issue on google cloud docs, api docs (still in beta), here but not success. I try to use timestamp as I use to save date on field, but for query arguments it does work.

Comment: I recommend using PHP-GDS (I am the author) : https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Comment: It has date property support.